# How to keep my TouchBar active when not focused

Tags: cocoa, appkit, macos-sierra, xcode8, nstouchbar

I'm trying to create a proxy app to provide touchbar functionality for an existing closed source app. I am able to communicate with the app through an api, but my touchbar disappears when it's not focused.

In the `NSTouchBar` documentation it says:

> On supported MacBook Pro models, the Touch Bar, above the keyboard, shows instances of the NSTouchBar class from the front-most app.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to force which touchbar is being displayed. I tried to not resign, which works somewhat, but then I lose focus from the application.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you found the answer by yourself. The Touch Bar is designed to only show app-specific controls.

From the Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/AbouttheTouchBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH104-SW1):

> The Touch Bar […] is a Retina display and input device that provides dynamic interface controls for interacting with content on the main screen. These controls offer quick access to system-level and app-specific functionality based on the current context.

Answer (score 0):

[touchbar-photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xgoB.jpg)

BetterTouchTool can do this. The question is how?